# my 3.5" touch screen inverts the input of the touch

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, touchscreen

when ever i touch the top right of the screen and move to the bottom right the mouse moves from the top left to the top right

i've already tried "display_rotate=2" and "lcd_rotate=2" but nothing seems to work.
if anyone could help that would be very appreciated

Comment: Provide more details to your question, like what screen you are using, raspberry pi model, what possible fix you have made and etc.

Comment: i am using a 3.5" touchscreen, the model is RP 3 model B+ and my previous fixes are listed above